# Installing Predis

Tags: php, redis

So I just started to learn Redis and tried to install it for PHP using this link :- https://github.com/nrk/predis

I installed it via composer and then ran :-

```
require 'autoload.php';
$client = new Predis\Client(array('host' => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 6379, array("prefix" => "php:")));

$client->set("string:k", "something");
```

However, this generates error :-

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Predis\Configuration\Options' not found in /Library/WebServer/Documents/redis/2/src/Client.php on line 74

Error: Class 'Predis\Configuration\Options' not found in /Library/WebServer/Documents/redis/2/src/Client.php on line 74
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Add `use Predis\Client` and `use 'Predis\Configuration\Options'` to your script head

Comment: Tried, still get the same error.

Comment: Is the pathing correct? Do the files even exist?

Comment: Yes, tested it. Files do exist at those paths.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register **`Predis Autoloader`** like this

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'; //autoload vendor see https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

$client = new Predis\Client(array('host' => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 6379, array("prefix" => "php:")));

$client->set("string:k", "something");
```

Comment: Just changing the directory name wouldn't fix the error mate. The error is something else.

Comment: @NikloYa what is your directory structure?

Comment: Here it is :-https://gyazo.com/d2992384949108796108da1097c312a1

The file I'm running is "test.php"

Comment: @NikloYa check now I hope it will solve your problem also check composer documentation